# Matrix with text besides it behavior weird after equal symbol

Tags: blkarray

I tried to add some text beside a matrix to illustrate it, then I found a solution using package `blkarray`. Following is the code, and it succeeds to add some text right to the matrix.

```
\[\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
\begin{block}{(cc)r}
A & B & \text{text one}\\
C & D & \text{text two}\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}\]

\[M=\begin{blockarray}{ccc}
\begin{block}{(cc)r}
A & B & \text{text one}\\ 
C & D & \text{text two}\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}\]
```

Then the result after typeset:[image]

Pls see the second guy, why the Matrix move "upwards" a little bit? The equal sign doesn't show up in the middle of the matrix and it looks weird. So my question:

1). Is there any way to adjust the code and make the matrix be symmetry about the equal sign?

2). Do you know any other package/better way to add text beside a matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

No need for `blkarray` for such a simple case, an easier option is to concatenate two arrays side-by-side. The left array can be a `pmatrix` to automatically get the round parens.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ 
C & D  
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{array}{c}
\text{text one}\\ 
\text{text two}
\end{array}
\]

\[
M=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\ 
C & D  
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{array}{c}
\text{text one}\\ 
\text{text two}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here I use a not-often-used feature of the `tabstackengine` package that allows the mode of stacks to be different than that of TABstacks.  So I make the defaults stacks in "text" mode and TABstacks in "math" mode.  Then I can avoid the need to apply `\text{}` to the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\stackText
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\parenMatrixstack{
A & B \\ 
C & D  
}
\Centerstack{
text one\\
text two
}
\]
\[
M=
\parenMatrixstack{
A & B \\ 
C & D  
}
\Centerstack{
text one\\
text two
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Left{text}{delimiter}` feature of `blkarray`, if there's nothing else on the line. Or you can  use a plain `pmatrix`  followed by a `tabular`. Note both solutions are centred differently:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{blockarray}{\Left{$ M ={} $}{(}cc)l}
A & B & \text{text one}\\
C & D & \text{text two}
\end{blockarray}\]

\[M=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}l}
text one\\
text two
 \end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would stick with the `array` environment, possibly enirched by `multirow` and `bigdelim`. It's a bit of a pain to mess around with spaces, but I posted an example to prove how to do it.

The details are in `multirow` documentation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,multirow,bigdelim}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc@{\,}lc}
\ldelim( {2}{0pt}&
A&B&\rdelim){2}{0.5em}&\text{text one}\\
&C&D& &\text{text two}\\
\end{array}
\]
\[
M=\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{\,}lc}
\ldelim( {2}{0pt}&
A&B&\rdelim){2}{0.5em}&\text{text one}\\
&C&D& &\text{text two}\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]